# Jquery - animating a sliding effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, sliding

Here is the javascript function in which I am trying to bring about a sliding effect.

What I want is, upon clicking the right button (green coloured button), the sliding effect should replace the tab with another tab, all are block elements.

However, the effect is not working & I am sure I am doing something wrong with the jquery code. (the fade effect works fine on the left button (orange coloured button).

```
    function activateRightTab()
{
    var eTabIndDiv = document.getElementById ("feature_tabs_indicators").children[0];
    var iIndsCount = eTabIndDiv.childNodes[1].children.length;
    var direction = "right";
    if (iActiveNo < iTabsCount - 1 && iActiveNo >= 0)
    {
        iActiveNo = iActiveNo + 1;
        if (iActiveNo != 1 || iActiveNo != 0)
        {
            $(eTabsDiv.children[iActiveNo - 1]).stop() .animate({"left" : "300px"}, 500);
            eTabsDiv.children[iActiveNo - 1].style.display = "none";
            eTabIndDiv.children[iActiveNo - 1].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(122,121,198)";            
        }
        **$(eTabsDiv.children[iActiveNo]).stop() .animate({"left" : "300px"}, 500);**
        eTabsDiv.children[iActiveNo].style.display = "block";
        eTabIndDiv.children[iActiveNo].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,100,200)";        
    }
    activateFeaturesContainer(direction);
    return iActiveNo;
}
```

Here is the complete code (rather long) but it gives an idea of the effect I am trying to achieve.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wBpq7/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this: http://www.apple.com/macbookair/

For that, you first have to give `div#features` an `overflow: hidden`, otherwise, the content is not hidden while traveling to the left/coming in from the right.

You then have to position the new `ul` just outside the the viewable area and make it visible, otherwise the new content doesn't come in from the right (assuming it is what you want). In your case, you have to set `left: 292; display: block`. Now, you select both the old and new `ul` and apply an animation of `left: '-=292px'`. You then hide the old one. That should about do it.

```
var jNew = $(eTabsDiv.children[iActiveNo]);
var jOld = $(eTabsDiv.children[iActiveNo-1]);
jNew.css({
   'left': 292,
   'display': 'block'
});
jNew.add(jOld).stop(true).animate({
   'left': '-=292px'
}, function() {
   jOld.hide();
});
```

#### Notes:

- Because of `overflow: hidden`, you have to set a clearly defined height. `height: auto` has no meaning anymore since the div does not grow with its content anymore. Ideally, you adjust the height via JS to its children.
- I am working with the static values in your code to make a simple explanation. If `div#features` ever changes width, you have to change it in the code too. For better maintenance, I'd suggest you get the width of `div#features` with `.outerWidth()`, and base your animation off of that value

Comment: You can render it with height: auto and overflow: visible, get the height, then switch to overflow: hidden and play the first frame of the animation. Because JS is synchronous - nothing is rendered until a block of JS is done executing - the user never sees the box jump in height.

Comment: I guess it also works that way. However, the basic mechanics for the actual slide animation are still valid.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the extra length by adding the code. Problem was actually with the syntax of jquery (which I am still trying to get the hang of). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're really trying to do is create a div sitting in between the left and right buttons that has inside it 5 li tags that sit in a horizontal row, and then move them like a carousel to the left and right as the user clicks the left and right buttons.

Unfortunately if you use a DOM Inspector in any browser you'll see that the way you've put together your CSS, the 5 li tags actually run in a vertical column, causing the code to freak out a bit.

I'd put a div around the ul id=tabs and set it to exactly the width that the tabs currently occupy, and overflow: hidden. Then I'd make the ul inside be the width of the 5 elements, and shift it's left property by the width of one tab each time left or right is clicked.

You could also take a look at the source for this:
http://www.baijs.nl/tinycarousel/ (top-right, "Source")
or use it for your animation.

Comment: Thank you for helping out Chris. Cheers.